# Inline if statement inside ng-click to run one of two functions

Tags: angularjs

Is is possible to have something like:

```
<div ng-click="someVar == '1' ? functionOne() : functionTwo() ">
  Click me!
</div>
```

So depending what `someVar` is, `ng-click` would either run `functionOne` or `functionTwo`.

Comment: Yes, it is possible [working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/HyY4gcnCxbbuMMfKPX7n?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest creating "handlers" for this:

```
<div ng-click="functionThree(someVar)">
  Click me!
</div>

function functionThree(someVar){
    someVar == '1' ? functionOne() : functionTwo(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can do it.

```
<div ng-click="obj.length>1  ? functionOne() : functionTwo() ">
   Click me!
</div>
```